# Create an UIImage from NSString

Tags: nsstring, uiimage, nsdata

my problem is: i get from webservices an image. this is stored in NSString. and now i want show it as UIImage. But I dont know how to do it.

how i can convert data from NSString in NSData?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below methods for converting string to data

```
[NSData dataFromBase64String:yourString];
 [NSData dataFromBase64EncodedString:yourString]
```

Comment: Warning: NSData may not respond to 'dataFromBase64String'

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[yourString UTF8String] length:[yourString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];